# Launching Salesforce Flow and Passing Variables from Website Contact Form

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, website-integration

I'm currently working on a project and need some guidance.

I'm looking into launching a flow on Salesforce and passing variables from a contact form submission on my website. Any suggestions on where I should begin? Appreciate any insights or advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any variables that you create in the flow with the Available for input flag set will automatically be set when your contact form posts to Salesforce. You don't need to do anything special.